# Sharing cookies between uiwebview and afnetworking

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, afnetworking

I'm writing an app that uses afnetworking in some portions and a webview in others.

Is it possible that both can reference the same cookie jar?

For example, I would like for a session that started in the webview to be available in the afnetworking calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing session between AFNetworking and UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540108/sharing-session-between-afnetworking-and-uiwebview)