# Sharing session between AFNetworking and UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-3, nshttpcookiestorage

Is it possible to share `AFNetworking` session with UIWebView? I used `AFNetworking` to login to remote server, but the UIWebView have no idea about the session being created by `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `AFNetworking` and `UIWebView` share the same cookies storage. So we don't need any special technique to let `UIWebView` "share" a session initialized by `AFNetworking`, or any native session-based request which uses `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to store cookie. In my situation, the `UIWebView` did not find shared session to be useful, just because the session initialized by `AFNetworking` has lacked of a cookie which was sent only when browsing the site with a browser.

And here is what I did to solve the problem:

```
// Open a request to remote server with a User-Agent string set to the request header.
// We'll have browser-specific cookies in NSHTTPCookieStorage
NSString *userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[manager GET:kRemoteServerUrl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Done");
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}];
```

Above code will ensure that we have all browser-specific cookies in NSHTTPCookieStorage, hence let the `UIWebView` share any session initialized by native login routine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the UIWebView+AFNetworking category's to call `loadRequest`.

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/Categories/UIWebView+AFNetworking.html